# Is a btrfs RAID1 mountable if the added device isn't available/offline/failed/degraded?

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid, raid-1, btrfs

Assume I created a RAID1 with `btrfs`'s functions (`btrfs device` and `btrfs balance` subcommands instead of `mdadm`) like so:

```
btrfs device add /dev/sdxZ /dev/sdxY
btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid1 -mconvert=raid1 /dev/sdxZ
```

Is a `/dev/sdxZ` mountable if if pull the plug on `/dev/sdxY` (would it make a difference whether this happens during the sytem's running or between shutdown and boot)?

The following sources don't contain usable information:

- https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID56
- `man btrfs device` (doesn't mention availability after failure, only after explicit removal with `btrfs device remove`)
- `man btrfs balance`

I'm using `btrfs-progs` 3.19.1 on Linux 4.0-rc7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but the partition will need to be mounted in degraded mode. From the wiki documentation on multiple devices:

> Before replacing the device you will need to mount the array, if you have a missing device then you will need to use the following command:
>
> `sudo mount -o degraded /dev/sda1 /mnt`

The full procedure for replacing a failed device in a redundant array is here:

https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Using_Btrfs_with_Multiple_Devices#Replacing_failed_devices